# Need to fix apt repositories in 5.1.3

Tags: release-hera

I just installed elementary OS 5.1.3 and when I click check for updates, it opens the appcenter which reports errors with the apt repositories:

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hera-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you haven't changed anything? Because I really don't get what's happened here.

The issue is that it's pointing to "hera" in the repository, which doesn't exist. It has to be "bionic". I know there's a way to reset apt, but I'm not sure how it'll handle the PPAs of elementary, meaning, you'll have to edit them yourself.

You'll have to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and every file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and change every occurrence of "hera" to "bionic"

Here's a little guide to using sed. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/
It might be a good idea to make copies of the files you're editing beforehand, just in case. :)

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I used a modified elementaryos iso because my machine is a late 2006 iMac. It has a 64 bit cpu and a 32 bit EFI.